# Incluir registro e retornar botão desabilitado sem refresh

Tags: php, ajax

Eu fiz um botão `adicionar amigo`, como nas redes sociais, só que uso formulario pra fazer isso, ele manda o usuário para uma outra pagina. Queria alguma forma dinâmica sem atualizar a pagina, ao clicar no botão é feito o insert no banco de dados e retorna o botão desabilitado não deixando o usuário acionar o botão mais de uma vez.

Esta é a página  onde o usuário adiciona um usuário:

**amigos.php**

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" amigo_id="<?php echo $id; ?>">Adicionar amigo</a>
```

Ao clicar no botao teria que executar esse arquivo em segundo plano sem atualizar a página.

**adicionar-amigo.php**

```
<?php 


session_start();

$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
$conn->set_charset("utf8");

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("<font color='red'>A conexão falhou: </font>" . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO amigos (id_usuario,id_amigo,data_adc)
VALUES ('$_SESSION[UsuarioID]', '$_GET[id]', now() )";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Amigo adicionado!";
} else {
    echo "Erro: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro coloque uma `class` no botão para identificá-lo para o `javascript`:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary botao-adicionar-amigo" amigo_id="<?php echo $id; ?>">Adicionar amigo</a>
```

Agora utilize essa `class` como seletor no evento [`click`](https://api.jquery.com/click/):

```
    $(".botao-adicionar-amigo").click(function() {

      var amigo_id = $(this).attr('amigo_id'); //Capturando o atributo amigo_id

     //Post ajax para sua página php, sem refresh
     $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "adicionar-amigo.php",
       data: {id: amigo_id},
       success: function(resposta){
          console.log(resposta);
       }
     });

      //Esconde o botão
      $(this).css('display','none'); 

    });
```

Aqui tem a documentação do post via ajax https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Na sua página `php` continue fazendo a mesma coisa. Ela não mudará nada.

Talvez você precise tratar o retorno de alguma forma específica, no exemplo acima está sendo devolvido ao console do navegador, mas você pode fazer da forma que preferir.

O botão, após executar a função `click` receberá o atributo `hidden` do `css`. Você também pode trocar para aquele que for melhor para seu cenário.